# keras understanding a dense layer shape output

Tags: keras, tensor, tf.keras

I have a two dimensional tensor of shape (30812x2). I would like to build a very simple autoencoder model using it:

I tried the following:

```
input_obj = keras.Input(shape=(30812,2,))
encoded = layers.Dense(300, activation='relu')(input_obj)
decoded = layers.Dense(61624, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)
decoded = layers.Reshape((30812,2))(decoded)
autoencoder = keras.Model(input_obj, decoded)
```

I get an error:

```
total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [30812, 61624], output_shape = [30812, 2]
```

I suspect i'm not reshaping right in the beginning but can't get the exact syntax?

Comment: While I'm glad you [found a solution](/revisions/77693516/3), questions and answers are separate fields on Stack Overflow. Please relocate your solution to the answer field below. Including the solution in the body of the question without posting an answer will make the system believe this question has not received any answers. Posting your answer in the answer field and [self-accept your answer after 48 hours](/help/self-answer) will indicate this question has been authoritatively answered and prevent system level actions that apply to unanswered questions.